# count how many letters and which letters in a file not working properly

Tags: c#

I get random chars like `a = 49 '1'`  `d = 52 '4'` (should be `a = a`   `d = d`)

I tried putting other stuff on "temp[j]" but nothing give the desired result i am stuck on this for more than 2 weeks

```
lettres = Convert.ToChar(temp[j] - '0');// Convert.ToChar(temp[j]);// - '0');
switch (lettres)
    {
         case 'A':
              numbers[0] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'B':
              numbers[1] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'C':
              numbers[2] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'D':
              numbers[3] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'E':
              numbers[4] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'F':
              numbers[5] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'G':
              numbers[6] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
         case 'H':
              numbers[7] += 1;
              numberos = numbers;
              break;
```

temp[j] is a string like banana and j is part of a for loop so suppose its  1 the result should be numbers[0] +=1 since lettres should be A but it is instead 49'1' then the switch doesnt do anything since '1' is not a case

Comment: What is your desired outcome and what happens exactly unexpectedly?

Comment: it should say what is each letter of the word and put the numbers in the numbers[] but it doesnt say what is the letter just 49 '1' and i cant fix it

Comment: `a = 49 '1'`, the 49 is the [ascii decimal representation for `1`](http://www.asciitable.com/)..  i have no idea what you mean with `49 '1'`? could you post your `temp` array contents and expected output? its kind of hard to guess what you want to do..

Comment: Post your input and ur desired output

Comment: i know its the ascii but i cant put it to normal chars regardless what i try to do

Comment: Please, like @lagripe stated, post your input and desired output. Otherwise, it's guessing what you want to accomplish...
Whats the datatype of `lettres`, what is the content of `temp`?

Comment: There are so many better ways to do this.

Comment: temp[j] is a string like banana and j is 1 the result should be numbers[0] +=1 since lettres should be A but it is instead 49'1' then the switch doesnt do anything since '1' is not a case

Comment: trailmax yea there is but im new and i dont really know much stuff

Comment: Please edit your original post.  Don't try to give details and want scenarios in comments.  Takes too much and harder for the rest of us to help.  Edit original post please.

Comment: It remains guessing as your explanation is really unclear. Nonetheless I take a shot at the dark: it's maybe a problem of capital case? Maybe `case 'a': case 'A':` solves your problem?
But as @trailmax said, there are maybe much better ways to do that, but we can't show you one without a complete code example and/or exact explanation

Comment: infotoni91 no because in debug mode i just get the 49'1' and not A or a

Comment: can you put your code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and attach the share link to your post? and write the expected input and expected output?

Comment: I think your conversion "temp(j) - '0'" is incorrect. That works fine for digits but would result in an error when applying that conversion to letters. Per your example, 'a' is 0x61. You subtract '0' (0x30), resulting in 0x31 which is the '1' you're seeing. Google "ASCII CODE". (I THINK)

Comment: Like @Lincoln_MA says: You subtract '0' from 'a' which gives '1' or 49...Absolutely right output to your input. And please stop writing 49'1' as 49 and '1' is absolutely the same

Comment: then how do i solve it?

Comment: I, for my part, actually don't exactly know WHAT to solve. Why are you subtracting '0'?

Comment: do you want to create an indexed file for the text file ?

Comment: yea i think i fixed it just a dumb mistake from the capital letters dammit

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
Dictionary<char, int> frequencies = text
                .GroupBy(c => c)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Also, add this on top:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 2):

from your question what I understand is

```
string str2 = "banana";
var r = str2.ToUpper().GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        t = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```